# Date - prev. year and the current = sysdate

Tags: sql, oracle, date

So, i want to add the next "interval" as condition :

```
SELECT sum(x.count) FROM x WHERE
```

Current:

```
TO_CHAR(x.date,'YYYYW') = TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYYW')
```

OUTPUT:

```
20181 = 20181
```

I want smthing like this:

```
(TO_CHAR(x.date,'YYYYW') and TO_CHAR(x.date-365,'YYYYW'))  = (TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYYW') and TO_CHAR(SYSDATE-365,'YYYYW'))
```

Expected output:

```
20171 and 20181 = 20181
20172 and 20182 = 20182
and so on...
```

to_char(DATE,'W') is not good, because i have older dates than 2017.. and i dont want to select them.

Comment: Can you detail what do you want?

Comment: I want all week1,2,3,4 from year 2017, 2018..so if its week 1(sysdate), i want to get all week 1..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not quite sure what you really want todo, but couldn't you just use the following query:

```
SELECT sum(x.count) FROM x WHERE x.date >= trunc(sysdate, 'W')
```

`trunc(sysdate, 'W')` gives you the start of the week as date and then you just sum over all datarows that are newer...

Comment: Yep, but i dont want sumarize x.count before years 2017... so that's the problem with to_char(DATE,'W') // trunc(sysdate, 'W') .. I have x.count @year 2014 for example..

Comment: trunc(sysdate, 'W') allways gives you the date of the current year, so you only get the sum of records from this year. If you also want record from last year you can add `OR x.date between trunc(sysdate - 365, 'W') and trunc(sysdate - 365, 'W') + 7`...

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
WHERE (TO_CHAR(x.date, 'YYYYW') = TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYYW')) OR
      (TO_CHAR(x.date, 'YYYYW') = TO_CHAR(SYSDATE - 365, 'YYYYW'))
```